# Как требовать от унаследованных классов предоставить реализацию метода c++?

Tags: c++

Необходимо в родительском класс в определенном методе строго требовать от всех унаследованных классов предоставить реализацию этого метода. Как это осуществить? А также позволить унаследованным классам использовать свои перегруженные реализации других определенных методов , но не требовать этого?

Comment: На мой личный взгляд это выглядит как изначально некорректный дизайн структуры\иерархии классов, и, возможно, ее стоит переписать заново. Однако, технически, вопрос легитимный.

Comment: дык, второе — сделать их виртуальными; первое — сделать их чисто виртуальными... или в чём вопрос?

Comment: @Fat-Zer чисто виртуальные методы подойдут, если метод не определен в базовом классе. Вопрос говорит об обратном. Или это мне бредится? Походу дело реально бредится... Надо больше спать. ПРошу прощения.

Comment: Ну, например, VC++ позволяет определить (дать тело) и чисто виртуальной функции. А потом, в условии непонятна семантика слова "определенный" - это метод, который определен (с телом), или синоним "некоторый", "указанный"? "В некотором методе требовать..."